# Matching date format for +XX hours

Tags: php

I need to be able to match a date format of this type:

```
Y-m-d\TH:i:s\+11:00
```

But instead of the +11:00, I would like it to be +XX:00 where XX can be any number.

I'm using

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\+11:00', $date);
```

And it throws an error if the +XX changes from 11.

Comment: You want to use the format specifier `P` in that place - _“difference to UTC with colon between hours and minutes”_, see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If my format is: Y-m-d\TH:i:s\+P:00 it still throws an error. Even trying Y-m-d\TH:i:s\P or Y-m-d\TH:i:s\+P doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need escape characters in this way:

```
$date = '2017-08-20\T12:13:14\+11:00';
print_r( DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\\\\\TH:i:s\\\P', $date) );

$date = '2017-08-20T12:13:14+11:00';
print_r( DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $date) );
```